# MYSQL table in table

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I want to make a database that tracks the activity of members, so adds all the stuff they do. 
But to do that I think that I need a nested table, as the first would contain the user and his info and then a subtable to store all the events.

Can this be done in mysql?

So like:

```
 username 
 email 
 telephone 
 events-> event 1, event 2, event 3
```

with each event having `date, participants and time`

Comment: Yes it can be done? What have you tried?

Comment: Rather than "nesting" tables, you want each record in your Event table to reference a row of your Member table using a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at a many to many approach.

So

```
Table Users
- UserID
- UserName
- User Etc.
```

Then

```
Table Activities
- ActivityID
- ActivityName
- ActivityGroupdID
- Acticity Etc.
```

Then

```
Table UserActivities
- UserID
- ActivityID
- Link Etc.
```

Further to this, you could think about user security, or roles where a user belonging to a specific group, might have access to specific activities.

Comment: If you need to support the possibility that an Activity applies to more than one User, then this will work. If every Activity has a single User, then you can do one-to-many using a simple foreign key.